# Can the verb "see" form the present participle "seeing?"

Tags: american-english, british-english, gerunds, present-participles

I red somewhere that "see" doesn't form present participle. Is it true? For exemple in sentence:

1. I'm seeing my doctor today.

We use -ing form. Can we call it present participle in sentence or should we call it differently?

Comment: **Seeing** that you've successfully used a present participle of 'see', I conclude that you have disproved the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example used "seeing" as a *present continuous* to indicate immediate future.  It is NOT used as a participle.

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html

A participle is a verb form used as an adjective.

- a seeing-eye dog
- the all-seeing God

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participles.htm

But, we say a *sighted* person (meaning *not blind*), rather than a *seeing* person. Perhaps that's what your friend meant.

Comment: We form the present continuous by using the verb *BE* and the present participle! That's what that word is!!! The Present Continuous is the name for the construction, which includes both *BE* and the participle. Your point about not  using the participle of *BE* as an attributive modifier is however, insightful and correct.

Comment: - well kind of correct. After all we have  [all-seeing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22all+seeing%22&oq=%22all+seeing%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j5j0.3781j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=all-seeing)

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not true. Almost all verbs can be formed into an -ing form. *Seeing* is perfectly acceptable.

The main exceptions are the helping verbs, such as *can, could, will, would, ought, may, might, shall, and should*, and the defective verb *beware*, which itself can only be used in imperative and infinitive forms.

Comment: Modal verbs have no infinitive, no past participle, no endings as -s or -ing. I have never seen an imperative of a modal verb.

Comment: I should have been more clear: "Beware" can only be used in imperative/infinitive.